# How to solve “Error validating stack policy" "Unsupported action" when using Serverless?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

I am trying to write a Serverless script to create an AWS lambda function with S3 permissions.

However, I am getting `Error validating stack policy to be applied after stack update: Unsupported action 'lambda:InvokeFunction' in statement {}`.

Here is a snippet of my `serverless.yml` so far:

```
    service: {{lambda_function_name}}
    # You can pin your service to only deploy with a specific Serverless version
    # frameworkVersion: "=X.X.X"

    provider:
      name: aws
      runtime: nodejs8.10
      role: {{&roleArn}}
      stage: {{stage}}
      region: {{region}}
      vpc:
        securityGroupIds:
          - {{securityGroupId1}}
        subnetIds:
          - {{subnetId1}}
          - {{subnetId2}}
      stackPolicy:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: "s3.amazonaws.com"
          Action: "lambda:InvokeFunction"
          Condition:
            ArnLike:
              AWS:SourceArn:
                - "arn:aws:s3:::{{bucket}}"

    package:
      include:
        - app.js
        - node_modules/**
        - src/**
        - bin/**
        - tests/**
```

Note that values inside of curly braces are environment variables.

Everything works until I try adding the permissions. What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to create a resource.

https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/s3/

In response to my negative votes, I thought I would give further explanation.

With serverless you can use pure Cloudformation. I created a custom resource to add the required permissions to my S3 bucket.

```
# resource to add S3 lambdainvoke permissions
resources:
  Resources:
    # Cloudformation key, can be called anything.
    LambdaPermission:
      Type: "AWS::Lambda::Permission"
      Properties:
        FunctionName:
          "Fn::GetAtt": # grabs function arn
            - AppLambdaFunction
            - Arn
        Principal: "s3.amazonaws.com"
        Action: "lambda:InvokeFunction"
        SourceAccount:
          Ref: AWS::AccountId
        SourceArn: "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name"
```

I hope this helps anyone encountering the same issue I was having.

As for adding the trigger, that can only be done through Cloudformation on a bucket that does NOT already exist.

The workaround in my case for that was to simply use AWS CLI in my deployment to add the trigger on an existing S3 bucket.

There is a serverless plugin out there called serverless-plugin-existing-s3 that was designed to allow adding triggers to existing S3 buckets, but I have discovered bugs with this plugin. That's why I will stick with using the CLI for adding the trigger.

https://github.com/matt-filion/serverless-external-s3-event

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to get this to do the following:

1. Create a Lambda function
2. Create an S3 bucket
3. Allow the Lambda function to write to the S3 bucket

Here is the `serverless.yml` extract that did it:

```
provider:
  iamRoleStatements:
   - Effect: "Allow"
     Action:
      - "s3:PutObject"
      - "s3:GetObject"
     Resource:
      Fn::Join:
        - ""
        - - Fn::GetAtt:
            - S3BucketMyBucket
            - Arn
          - "/*"

resources:
  Resources:
    S3BucketMyBucket:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties:
        BucketName: ${self:custom.cfg.s3BucketName}

functions:
  process:
    handler: handler.process
    events:
      - s3:
        bucket: ${self:custom.dre.s3BucketName}
        event: s3:ObjectCreated:*

custom:
  cfg:
    s3BucketName: "mybucket-${opt:stage}"
```

The key is that by splitting `/functions/process/events/s3` into multiple fields (`bucket` and `event`) then it won't try to create the S3 bucket.  When it's all listed on one line (without an event) then it tries to create the bucket and you end up with a naming conflict as it tries to create two buckets with the same name (one from `/functions` and one from `/resources`).